# Por qué el background the un div toma como ancestro al viewport si coloco porcentajes como dimensiones del background

Tags: html, css, position, porcentaje

cómo están?

Tengo una página web cuya estructura es la siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </html>
    <body>
        <div>
        ....
        </div>
        <div>
        ....
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
            <div>
                <div class="bloque_dash">
                    <div class="titulo_2"
                        <div class="titulo_2">
                            <h2>...</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenido">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="tile01">...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

y el archivo de estilos en CSS tiene estilos globales y del :root como siguen

```
  * {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
:root {
    /*-----Transiciones------*/
    --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
    --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
    --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
    --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

los estilos para el `<div>` de clase tile01 van como siguen

```
.cuerpo_sistema .controles_sistema .bloque_dash .contenido .box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:95%;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:5px solid #111111;
    background-color: none;
  }

  .cuerpo_sistema .controles_sistema .bloque_dash .contenido .box .tile01 {
  position: absolute
  margin: auto;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center 0px,800px 2500px, #111111 10%, #0099ff 10.4%);
  background-size:40px 200%; 
  background-attachment: local;  
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-clip: border-box; 
  background-position:0px 100%;
  animation-name: wave-animation; 
  animation-duration: 3s;  
  animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

 @keyframes wave-animation
 { 
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 40px 50%;
  }
 100% {
    background-position: 80px 100%;
  }
 }
```

los cuales consisten en una animación de agua con oleaje extraída de un ejemplo en internet.

La pregunta es por qué si coloco el background-size con dimensiones en porcentajes, entonces se establecen los porcentajes en viewport y no del bloque, se que está relacionado con la propiedad `position` establecida en `absolute` pero con todo lo leído por mi hasta ahora no entiendo por cual razón toma las dimensiones internas relativas al viewport.

He leído que cuando el background-size está establecido en porcentajes, las dimensiones se relacionan al ancestro más cercano, sin embargo inicialmente pensaba que el ancestro más cercano era el `<div>` contenedor quien es `tile01` pero no es así.

Como última comentario, si quito la posición establecida en absolute o, la dejo en absoluta pero coloco explícitamente el background-atachment como local entonces el background-size si adopta dimensiones internas basadas en porcentajes del bloque inmediato contenedor.

en la explicación de [position en css de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position#posicionamiento_absoluto) se habla de que se hace relativo al ancestro posicionado y en caso contrario relativo al bloque contenedor inicial el cual es el  en este caso, lo que no se es a qué se refieren con ancestro posicionado.
Entonces, alguien puede explicarme por qué pasa esto?.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen, la solución a tu problema sería añadir `position: relative` al ancestro que desees que contenga el elemento posicionado absolutamente.

```
.cuerpo_sistema .controles_sistema .bloque_dash .contenido .box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:95%;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:5px solid #111111;
    background-color: none;
    position: relative;
  }
```

**Explicación**

Todo elemento posicionado absolutamente se sale del flujo del documento, a menos que uno de sus padres se encuentre posicionado, en cuyo caso éste será el que contendrá el elemento.

Un elemento se considera posicionado siempre que presente cualquier tipo de `position` que no sea `static`. Como todos los elementos vienen configurados por defecto como `position:static` (y, por lo tanto, se consideran "no posicionados"), `.tile01` es incapaz de detectar automáticamente el contenedor al que quieres que se supedite.

Por eso debes añadirle a `.box` algún otro parámetro para posicionarlo. Como en tu caso lo que quieres es que `.box` sí que respete el flujo del documento, la opción apropiada es `position:relative`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bettylex, ya me queda claro.